# Im trying to embed aspx web form into html page

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a question and I am still learning. Why does my web form appear as code when I publish my site, while it looks fine on my visual studio compiler as illustrated on the photo

[Visual Studio Compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvn1A.jpg)

[Published Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtoEI.jpg)

Comment: It would seem that your domain cannot run aspnet.

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: Use hosting that supports .Net